# REST route from a plugin not working if WordPress is installed in a subdirectory

Tags: plugins, rest-api, namespace

This question is basically a copy from the trac ticket I created [#42973](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42973).

On the [Theme Sniffer](https://github.com/WPTRT/theme-sniffer) plugin I replaced `admin-ajax.php` with `REST` endpoints.

So when you want to run a check against the theme the route called to check your theme is something like

`https://example.com/wp-json/theme-sniffer/v1/sniff-run`

Now if I install WordPress in a subdirectory that's called `/test` the route should be

`https://example.com/test/wp-json/theme-sniffer/v1/sniff-run`

But that doesn't happen. The sniff run will try to access endpoint at `https://example.com/wp-json/theme-sniffer/v1/sniff-run` which doesn't exist!

The routes are added like this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'theme_sniffer_endpoint_init' );
/**
 * Register endpoints function
 *
 * @since 0.1.0
 */
function theme_sniffer_endpoint_init() {
        register_rest_route( 'theme-sniffer/v1', '/sniff-run', array(
                'methods'  => 'POST',
                'callback' => 'theme_sniffer_run_sniffer',
        ) );
        register_rest_route( 'theme-sniffer/v1', '/individual-sniff', array(
                'methods'  => 'POST',
                'callback' => 'theme_sniffer_individual_sniff',
        ) );
}
```

You can check the code [here](https://github.com/WPTRT/theme-sniffer/blob/master/inc/routes.php).

My guess is that if the plugin namespace isn't defined, the subdirectory will be ignored, and it will assume that the endpoint originates from the root folder.

I haven't looked in the detail at the REST architecture in WP (will do later in the week), but if that is the case, will the namespacing the plugin help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the URL is not good in the AJAX call

to correct that, modify the function `theme_sniffer_admin_scripts` in `inc/admin.php` to add the home URL to `wp_localize_script` :

```
"homeURL" => home_url(),
```

and then use this URL in the 2 AJAX calls in `js/admin.js` :

```
url: localizationObject["homeURL"] + '/wp-json/theme-sniffer/v1/sniff-run',
```

Comment: Ok, I think there is something like that being done in a PR I submitted [here](https://github.com/WPTRT/theme-sniffer/pull/79/files#diff-2e4737e5c747173509048bc9e2502946R63). I rewrote everything using ES6 and webpack. Once this is merged I think this should solve the issues of wrong routes. But thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I try the branch you send with the pull request and I have an error : https://github.com/dingo-d/theme-sniffer/tree/feature/rewrite-plugin-webpack  the backend page doesn't found `assets/build/scripts/application.js` and when I load `assets/dev/application.js` I have the JavaScript error `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` I am not a JavaScript expert then I cannot help you to solve this.

Comment: The code needs to be built first ;) That's probably why it won't work. I will fix this when the PR is merged, and I'll release a plugin ready .zip file. Thanks!